# Script for finding scheduled task wizards task info

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I know there is a command for finding the scheduled tasks of a computer but I want to get more information on the scheduled tasks themselves. I want to know when and what time a scheduled task will be performed ALONG with the name and area of the scheduled task. Any ideas?

Comment: The same command for finding also lists properties. `schtasks /query /tn "Task Name" /v /fo list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set TS = CreateObject("Schedule.Service")
TS.Connect("Serenity")

Set rootFolder = TS.GetFolder("\")

Set tasks = rootFolder.GetTasks(0)

If tasks.Count = 0 Then 
    Wscript.Echo "No tasks are registered."
Else
    WScript.Echo "Number of tasks registered: " & tasks.Count

    For Each Task In Tasks
    A=Task.Name
    A = A & " " & Task.NextRunTime
    wscript.echo A
    Next
End If
```

From Help, some of these are objects with other info in them.

RegisteredTask

Scripting object that provides the methods that are used to run the task immediately, get any running instances of the task, get or set the credentials that are used to register the task, and the properties that describe the task.

Methods
The RegisteredTask object defines the following methods.

```
Method Description 
GetInstances Returns all instances of the registered task that are currently running. 
GetSecurityDescriptor Gets the security descriptor that is used as credentials for the registered task. 
GetRunTimes Gets the times that the registered task is scheduled to run during a specified time. 
SetSecurityDescriptor Sets the security descriptor that is used as credentials for the registered task. 
RunEx Runs the registered task immediately using specified flags and a session identifier. 
Stop Stops the registered task immediately. 
Run Runs the registered task immediately.
```

Properties
The RegisteredTask object has the following properties.

```
Property Description 
Definition Gets the definition of the task. 
Enabled Gets or set a Boolean value that indicates if the registered task is enabled. 
LastRunTime Gets the time the registered task was last run. 
LastTaskResult Gets the results that were returned the last time the registered task was run. 
Name Gets the name of the registered task. 
NextRunTime Gets the time when the registered task is next scheduled to run. 
NumberOfMissedRuns Gets the number of times the registered task has missed a scheduled run. 
Path Gets the path to where the registered task is stored. 
State Gets the operational state of the registered task. 
XML Gets the XML-formatted registration information for the registered task.
```

Example Code [C++]
For more information and example code for this scripting object, see Time Trigger Example (Scripting) and Displaying Task Names and States (Scripting).

Requirements
Client Requires Windows Vista. 
Type Library Use Taskschd.tlb.

DLL Requires Taskschd.dll.

See Also
Task Scheduler Objects
Task Scheduler

Send comments about this topic to Microsoft

Build date: 10/2/2006
Language
C++

Show All
Requirements
Client Requires Windows Vista. 
Type Library Use Taskschd.tlb.

DLL Requires Taskschd.dll.
See Also
Task Scheduler Objects
Task Scheduler

Send comments about this topic to Microsoft

Build date: 10/2/2006