# It is possible to run a .vbs file with hidden attribute at startup?

Tags: cmd

I have a .vbs file with 's' and 'h' attributes set. I copied this file to startup folder but when I restart the PC, it doesn't execute it.
Is there a way to execute the .vbs file?

Comment: What about a scheduled task?

Comment: Interesting but when the user reboots the PC, someone needs to start something so we are back again at startup.

Comment: I can assure you that if you create a scheduled task, this is no longer the case.

Comment: Ok... I google it and it sounds nice. But it is possible to make a scheduled task in .vbs or .bat?

Comment: Sure. You can use the `schtasks` command.

Comment: Context changed a little bit but you should put it as an answear.

Comment: Done adding the answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394519/script-for-finding-scheduled-task-wizards-task-info for a VBScript way of using task scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if a hidden file can be executed in `Start Menu\Programs\Startup\`, but you can always create a scheduled task to run it.

With GUI, you can right-click on "My Computer" and select "Manage". Expand "Task Scheduler" on the left pane to a key anf then click "Create a new task" on the right pane and configure in the pop-up window as you want.

If you want to automate the process in a batch file or VBScript, use `schtasks.exe`. An example to launch Notepad at any user logon is like the following.

```
schtasks.exe /Create /SC ONLOGON /TN "Auto start Notepad" /TR "%SystemRoot%\System32\notepad.exe"
```

That line can be directly put into a batch file. If you want to do it in a VBScript script, use `WScript.Shell` object.