# How to create a task in task scheduler that runs every 30 minutes

Tags: vbscript

I would like to create a VBS file that creates a task in task scheduler that runs every 30 minutes. I already know how to create a task a task in task scheduler using VBS file.

I've already created a VBS file that creates a task in task scheduler which runs every Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday Sunday at 02:00 PM.

But What I really want is to create a task that runs every 30 minutes.

I wrote a bunch of codes but the part which interests me is the one below. and I guess it's the one holding the key to my question.

```
wShell.Run "SchTasks /Create /SC WEEKLY /D MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SUN /TN ""Basic Checking"" /TR ""C:\Creator.bat"" /ST 14:00", 0
```

Comment: Type `schtasks /create /?` and pay attention to `/sc` and `/mo`. Also see how to do this in VBScript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394519/script-for-finding-scheduled-task-wizards-task-info

Answer (score 0):

I was Able to Solve the issue by using this line... But let me add that I finally Understood that I need my task to be scheduled at a specific time and repeat every 30 minutes. So I used

```
wShell.Run "SchTasks /Create /SC MINUTE /MO 30 /TN ""Basic Checking"" /TR ""C:\Creator.bat"" /ST 14:00", 0
```

But If you want to eliminate that starting time parameter. You simply eliminate the /ST and you get

```
wShell.Run "SchTasks /Create /SC MINUTE /MO 30 /TN ""Basic Checking"" /TR ""C:\Creator.bat""", 0
```